# Анимация rotate jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Задача, чтобы при наведении бордеры крутились на 90deg. Нужно чтоб при наведении срабатывала анимация полностью, пока не закончится. Уже долго ищу ответ. Кто  знает как такое делается на jquery? Эффект с opacity получается, а вот rotate нет.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.box')
            .hover(function() {
                $('.border-first').stop().animate({ 
                    opacity: 0.2 
                }, 'slow');
            }, function() {
                $('.border-first').stop().animate({ 
                    opacity: 1 
                }, 'slow');
        });


    });
```

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 100px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }

 .box {
  margin: 0 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 300px;
 }
 .icon {
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px;
 }
 .icon img {
  width: 100%;
 }
 .border-first {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  top: 25px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  border: 3px solid #333333;
 }
 .border-second {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 25px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  border: 3px solid tomato;
 }

 .text {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #333;
  padding: 30px 0;
 }
```

```html
   <div class="wrap">
 <div class="box">
  <div class="icon">
   <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png" alt="icon">
  </div>
  <div class="border-first"></div>
  <div class="border-second"></div>
  <div class="text">
   Hello, A im super block with animation!!!
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
  <div class="icon">
   <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png" alt="icon">   
  </div>
  <div class="border-first"></div>
  <div class="border-second"></div>
  <div class="text">
   Hello, A im super block with animation!!!
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
  <div class="icon">
   <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png" alt="icon">
  </div>
  <div class="border-first"></div>
  <div class="border-second"></div>
  <div class="text">
   Hello, A im super block with animation!!!
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А обратная анимация вращения должна быть, когда убираем курсор из блока?

Comment: Если да, то как быть если убрали курсор с блока во время анимации? А если потом снова навели?

Comment: Анимация должна быть независимой: если навел, анимация началась, пока не закончится, повторное наведение во время анимации не срабатывает. нужно чтобы бордеры сделали поворот на 90 градусов

Comment: Я спрашивал про обратную анимацию - нужна она или нет? Больше интересует этот вопрос

Comment: Обратная анимация нужна